# Contrapositive Epsilon-Delta Limits?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

Is the contrapositive form of the epsilon-delta limit definition valid, or am I missing something?
-- If valid, are there any examples where it is easier in a proof?

---

\begin{align*}\scriptsize
\lim_{x\to c}
\;
f(x)=L\\
&\scriptsize\equiv\quad
\forall\epsilon\; 
(\;\exists\delta\;
(\, 0< \; \mid x-c \mid \; < \delta  \implies  \mid f(x)-L \mid \; < \; \epsilon
\,))
&\tiny(Defintion)\\
&\scriptsize\equiv\quad
\forall\epsilon\;
(\;\exists\delta\;
(\, \neg( \; \mid f(x)-L \mid \; < \; \epsilon ) \implies \neg(0< \; \mid x-c \mid \;
<
\delta
)
\,
))
&\tiny(Contrapositive)\\
&\scriptsize\equiv
\quad
\forall
\epsilon
\;
(
\;
\exists
\delta
\;
(
\,
\mid
f(x)-L
\mid
\;
\ge
\;
\epsilon
\implies
(\;0\ge\;\mid x-c\;\mid\;)\; \lor \;(\;\mid x-c\,\mid\;\ge \delta\;) \, )) &\tiny(a\lt b\lt c \ \equiv\ ((a<b)\land(b<c)),\;DM)\\
&\scriptsize\equiv
\quad
\forall
\epsilon
\;
(
\;
\exists
\delta
\;
(
\,
\mid
f(x)-L
\mid
\;
\ge
\;
\epsilon
\implies
\mid x-c\,\mid\;\ge \delta \, )) &\tiny(\ (0\ \not\gt\ \mid a \mid)\ \land\ (x\ \not=\ c)\ )\\
\end{align*}

---

I'm still trying to conceptualize this, so as to posit tests and extremal cases for validation... any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are looking for in terms of validation, maybe what you need to do is rewrite your argument in terms of natural language, in stead of logical symbolism. Everything you wrote is correct, and your conclusion is sound, but it is possible that all of the superfluous notation is confusing you.

Answer (score 1):

Of course the contrapositive form is valid, the logic you carried out was correct. Although right now, I can't think of any examples where the contrapositive form would be substantially easier than the standard definition (and I don't think I ever could), I'll convince you that it works. For example, consider $$\lim_{x \to 5} 3x-3 = 12$$

Using the standard definition, for all $\epsilon >0$ we must find a $\delta>0$ such that
$$0<|x-5|<\delta \Rightarrow |3x-15|<\epsilon$$

We would do some rearranging to get $$0<|x-5|<\delta \Rightarrow 3|x-5|<\epsilon$$ $$0<|x-5|<\delta \Rightarrow |x-5|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$$
and we would conclude that the implication is satisfied for $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{3}$

Now consider the contrapositive form $$|3x-15|\geq\epsilon \Rightarrow |x-5|\geq\delta$$

We can do the same rearranging to get
$$3|x-5|\geq\epsilon \Rightarrow |x-5|\geq\delta$$ $$|x-5|\geq\frac{\epsilon}{3} \Rightarrow |x-5|\geq\delta$$

and we would also conclude that the implication holds for $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{3}$